Being able to easily see how many deleted versus non-deleted posts I acted on
I am often curious how many total questions I have closed/reopened/edited/etc regardless which ones were later deleted. You can view these statistics on your profile, and selecting the desired tab, to see a list of votes and a number showing the total. However, unless you have moderator tools, the close/reopen and delete/undelete votes will only count non-deleted posts. Otherwise, you will see the total votes, with votes on deleted posts highlighted in red.
With up/downvotes, I can determine how many total votes I cast, and how many were on posts were subsequently deleted, by comparing the number of votes in the public votes cast table versus the number in the privates votes tab in my profile, which only counts votes on undeleted posts. These show that of the 2906 Stack Overflow questions I downvoted, 2906-319=2587 were later deleted. Up/downvotes seem to always only count non-deleted posts, regardless if you have moderator tools.
But there is no easy way to see how many total (counting deleted posts) close/reopen votes I have without moderator assistance, unless I have moderator tools, in which case, I will have no easy way, besides manually counting the red-highlighted ones, to determine the number of close/reopen votes I cast on questions which were later deleted.
My suggestion is, if I go to any of the tabs in my votes tab in my profile, I would appreciate if the number on top says:

XXX Votes (YYY Deleted)

Or similar, instead of just:

XXX Votes

Similarly, this could apply to revisions to see how many times you edited a post that was later deleted anyway.
Where the number on close/reopen/delete/undelete includes deleted posts if you have moderator tools, and excludes them if you do not.
I would find this useful because, although how you act on the information is up to you, this could give you an insight as to how well the final fate of posts align with your voting habits. For example, if a large fraction of posts I reopen vote are later deleted, maybe I am being too liberal with reopen votes, etc.
